# Identify transformation that turns images to the Dark Side

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform, wavelet-transform

Working on a new method to detect linear objects in images, I have found a transformation that turns the images into a spooky tangled network. My theory is that the transformed image shows the main paths of spatial coherence.

Is this kind of analysis already done in other field of image processing or with another application?

I show an example with a satellite image of a forest area:

[image: dark-side transform of forest area]

I have experience with image operations to identify features in images, like edges or straight lines, but I have never seen anything like this.

The method is based on several wavelet-transforms around each pixel, considering lines in all directions and selecting the angle with maximum convolution value. This operation results in two numbers per pixel: the maximum convolution and its corresponding angle, similar to the magnitude and phase of the Fourier analysis. In the above example, the convolution map is shown with its extreme values scaled to a gray map.

As suggested in the comments by @user1118321, I have compared the transformation with a Sobel filter:

[image: dark-side transform vs Sobel filter of forest area]

Sobel operator approximates the spatial derivatives of the image in each pixel. Using the classical 3x3 kernel, a first order approximation of the gradient vector is obtained that is typically used to highlight edges. My filter uses an arbitrary kernel size (32x32 in the above example) but does not approximate the spatial derivatives of any order. The image is convoluted against linear kernels that can be interpreted as local Hough transforms as pointed out in the comments by @Meisam. Selecting the kernel with maximum convolution value, the image is locally approximated as a line in the corresponding direction.

This hypothesis answers part of my question but the precise meaning of the paths present in the filtered image is still open. The paths seem to connect certain regions of the image, maybe spatially coherent or maybe just a visual artifact from the superposition of the local Hough transforms.

Comment: What you've described sounds a lot like a [Sobel Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) or other edge detectors that calculate the gradient magnitude and angle.

Comment: Such an amazing tranformation! Is this method have a special name?

Comment: @user1118321 What I see is more than an edge detector. It's kind of an edge detector and linear and circular Hough transform at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question on Image.sc Forum and [Gabriel](https://forum.image.sc/u/gabriel) responded with a technique called two-dimensional matched filters and a scientific paper from the late 80s.

*Chaudhuri et al. Detection of blood vessels in retinal images using two-dimensional matched filters. IEEE Trans Medical Imaging 1989, 8(3): 263-269* ([pdf](http://researchgate.net/search?q=10.1109/42.34715))

In this work, kernels with different orientations are used to identify smooth edges in retinal images. In my case, I wanted to identify blurred lines so I used circular kernels containing a line with different orientations.

[image: circular kernels with a line in different orientations]

Gabriel also took the time to process my example image using two-dimensional matched filters with similar results.

[image: two-dimensional matched filters]